# php session not work in ipad safari

Tags: php, ipad, session, safari

I have two php files.
one is index.php

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
    echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];
?>
```

one is /test/test.php

```
<?php session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["favcolor"];
?>
```

I load index.php and then test.php, but test.php return nothing in ipad. It works in all browsers but not in safari in ipad. Is anyone can help me?